# Guaranteeing that node is above all other nodes in group

Tags: javafx

I am currently trying to make a group of arcs, with text above them. This seems to be working, but for only half the cases. The other half is ending up below the arc node and is invisible.

I have tried using node.tofront() , toback() etc but it is still not changing anything.

```java
class pieslice extends Group{
pieslice(double centerx,double centery,double segpart,double totalseg){
            Text value= new Text(String.format("%.2f",worth));
            segment = totalseg;
            Arc innerArc=new Arc();
            Arc outerArc=new Arc();
            outerArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
            innerArc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
            value.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            innerArc.setStrokeWidth(1);
            innerArc.setRadiusX(150.0f);
            innerArc.setRadiusY(150.0f);
            outerArc.setRadiusX(innerArc.getRadiusX()+10);
            outerArc.setRadiusY(innerArc.getRadiusY()+10);
            outerArc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            innerArc.setStartAngle((360/segment)*segpart);
            outerArc.setStartAngle((360/segment)*segpart);
            innerArc.setCenterX(centerx);
            innerArc.setCenterY(centery);
            outerArc.setCenterX(centerx);
            outerArc.setCenterX(centery);
            innerArc.setLength(360/segment);
            outerArc.setLength(360/segment);
            innerArc.setStrokeWidth(1);
            innerArc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            innerArc.setFill(Color.color(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random()));
            value.setX(150);
            value.setFill(Color.BLACK);
            value.getTransforms().add(new Rotate((360/segment)*segpart+((360/segment)/2),0,0));
            System.out.println((360/segment)*segpart+((360/segment)/2));
            this.getChildren().add(outerArc);
            this.getChildren().get(0).setViewOrder(2);
            this.getChildren().add(innerArc);
this.getChildren().add(value);}
```

I would expect that since I am adding the two arcs (Inner and outer for aesthetic effect only) and then the text, that the text would be rendered above the shapes, but that is not the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to make your code a [mre] demonstrating the issue? It'd help to be able to run your code _as is_ (e.g. with hard-coded values) and see the problem.

Comment: So I took a look at it this morning and I'm not sure why but the text is now being drawn over the arcs, so I guess this problem is solved haha. Thank you for the reply though :)